# GZip: Python - How to get the file name of a particular line using gzip.open

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip

I have a '.tgz' file, I'm reading the content of the '.tgz' file using gzip.open. What is the fastest way to get the file name of a particular line?

```
with gzip.open('sample.tgz','r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        error = checkForError(line)
        if error:
            # get the file name in which that particular error line was present
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: If we assume that you are asking about multiple files zipped into a single zip file, then that will depend on what tool (i.e. `tar`) you used to combine the files before the archive was zipped.

Comment: Yes it it multiple files zipped into a single zip. It was done using tar.

Answer (score 0):

This functions but quite how useful it is, is anyone's guess.
Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29#Header for the header format.

```
import gzip
fin = gzip.open("test.txt.tar","r")
for i in fin:
    if "ustar" in i:
        fname,b = i.split("0",1)
        print fname
    else:
        print i
fin.close()
```

Note: this is for python 2.7.6 on Linux, assuming the archive was created with `tar czvf`